# What is this status effect?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Started up Fjordur and noticed a status effect. Googled it but haven't found any answers. What is this? It looks like a rock or obsidian with a red symbol on it that kinda looks like a spider.

Comment: Please post a picture of the symbol you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a Rune?

https://ark.wiki.gg/wiki/Runes

https://www.reddit.com/r/ARK/comments/vfjtnc/what_is_this_symbolstatuscondition_fjordur/

It's because you're near a collectible Rune, since that seems to be the only status effect that fits your description.